# Locked record after user abandonment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a locking challenge in my application. There is an `invoice` which gets created automatically when a `timesheet` is approved. The invoice needs to be adapted manually by an employee (adding VAT code, contact data, etc), so he clicks the `adapt` button. At that moment the `timesheet` gets the status `locked` so no changes can be made anymore to the timesheet.

This all works fine, except for one edge case: the employee clicks the `adapt` button but then doesn't do anything to the invoice. E.g. it goes to another screen, forgets about the invoice, etc. In that case the timesheet stays in `locked` state forever, while it should be unlocked.

What can I do to solve this? My current idea is to create a rake task which checks timesheets in `locked` state at a certain interval and removes the `locked` state when there is more than an hour gone between the current time and the timesheet `updated_at` time.

But maybe there is another strategy that can handle this case much better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current strategy you're using is a pessimistic one, I'd recommend using an optimistic strategy:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html

The result is if someone opens the page, goes to lunch and in the meantime another user updates the record, then when the user gets back from lunch and submits the form an exception will occur.

The next question will be how do you handle the exception?  Tell the user this has already been dealt with?  Show the user the conflicts so they can resolve them?

Comment: Thanks for this, although I have to decide if I want it to be pessimistic or optimistic locking...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the approach of gmail eg(when you leave the page before finishing your email he asks if you are really sure you want to leave this page if yes he discards the message)
in your case you should do the same and send an ajax request to unlock the record 
In all cases you will need to do the rake task just to handle cases shut as power switch off or browser crashing. but it would give better convenience to avoid locking a record for a whole hour except in very special cases such these